# Keyboard borked after update

Tags: usb, updates, keyboard, xubuntu, input-devices

I'm running Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a laptop, and recently ran a system update. After restarting, my keyboard no longer inputs to the OS. According to a quick online search, this is not uncommon, and plenty of possible solutions can be found - e.g. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` to update drivers. However, they all require use of the terminal, which, without keyboard input, I can't access.

USB input doesn't seem to be working either, I've plugged in a USB mouse and a keyboard and nothing happens. System did show a USB drive though when I tried that.

I have tried to get Onboard on-screen keyboard to work, but it hasn't shown up. Not sure if that's because I haven't found the setting yet, since it did work when I enabled it in LightDM lock screen.

Function keys still work, like turning on/off keyboard backlight.

If anyone can help me access the terminal, or offer some other solution, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you ssh into the system?

Comment: I get `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.7 port 22: Connection refused` it probably isn't enabled in my system and I don't know how I would enable it

Comment: Yeah, kind of a Hail Mary move. LIkely you'll need to boot to a live usb and fix your system.

Comment: Booted from a live usb now, but when I uninstall and reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all, it says `E: Package " xserver-xorg-input-all" has no installation candidate`. I've tried sudo apt update and upgrade first but still no luck. Not even sure if I'm modifying my xubuntu installation or just the system that's running off the usb with all this.

Comment: You have to take additional steps to be able to modify the actual installation after booting into a live CD, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) under "Update Failure".

Comment: I got it working, figured out how to run onboard. Thanks all for your input

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem. I added the screen keyboard , up on the man icon. However the return key was not working. So, I could write a command but could not execute it.
You might have several desktops to work with. At the login icon, before typing your logging a wheel appears at the right bottom of the screen. I get, in my environment the following desktops.

- LXDE
- Open Box
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu.xorg
- Unity.

The only one that worked for me was LXDE.
Even there I installed xserver.org.input.all but that did not help. I had to switch to LXDE for good. It is not bad but some key short cuts do not work.